# Python Poly3DCollection Is there a way to set edgecolor for specific edges

Tags: python, plot, visualization

I am plotting geodesic polyhedra to approximate the sphere and I want to color a great circle on the polyhedra in red. I have attached pictures of the input and output. [image: input] [image: goodangle] [image: badangle]

What I did was plot the polyhedra first with Poly3DCollections and then plotted the great circle, again with Poly3DCollections, but it only shows at certain angles. If I rotate the image the great circle is no longer visible. I have tried playing with the thickness and zorder but it doesn't always stay visible. My code is below:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy.linalg import norm
from operator import add
from itertools import combinations
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

def refine(Vertices,Edges,Faces,iterations):

    for i in range(iterations):

        # Initializing set of new vertices, new edges, and new faces

        counter = len(Vertices)-1

        newVertices = []
        newEdges = set()
        newFaces = set()    

        # Adding elements of newVertices and trivial elements of newEdges

        for edge in Edges:
            counter = counter+1
            newVertex = np.array([0,0,0])
            for vertex in edge:
                newVertex = np.add(newVertex,np.array(Vertices[vertex]))
        
                newEdge = frozenset({vertex,counter})
                newEdges.add(newEdge)
            newVertex = np.divide(newVertex,norm(newVertex,2))
            newVertices.append(tuple(newVertex))

        # Adding non-trivial elements of newEdges and elements of newFaces

        for face in Faces:
            middleFace=set()
            SpecialEdges=set()
            pairsOfSpecialEdges={(a,b) for a,b in combinations({edge for edge in newEdges if len(edge.intersection(face))==1},2) if (a & b) and len((a-face).intersection(b-face))==1}
            for pair in pairsOfSpecialEdges:
                for edge in pair:
                    SpecialEdges.add(edge)
            for vertex in face:
                incidentEdges={edge for edge in SpecialEdges if vertex in edge}
                newEdge=set()
                for edge in incidentEdges:
                    for v in edge:
                        if v==vertex:
                            continue
                        else:
                            newEdge.add(v)
                            middleFace.add(v)
                newEdges.add(frozenset(newEdge))
                newEdge.add(vertex)
                newFaces.add(frozenset(newEdge))
            newFaces.add(frozenset(middleFace))
        
        Vertices.extend(newVertices)
        Edges.clear()
        Edges.update(newEdges)
        Faces.clear()
        Faces.update(newFaces)

def main():
    
    # User input

    userInput1=int(input('\nSelect an initial polyhedron:\n\n 1) Tetrahedron\n 2) Octahedron\n 3) Icosahedron\n\n'))

    Vertices=[]
    Edges=set()
    Faces=set()
    
    if userInput1==1:
        Vertices=[(0.57735026918963,0.57735026918963,0.57735026918963),(0.57735026918963,-0.57735026918963,-0.57735026918963),(-0.57735026918963,0.57735026918963,-0.57735026918963),(-0.57735026918963,-0.57735026918963,0.57735026918963)]
        Edges={frozenset({0,1}),frozenset({0,2}),frozenset({0,3}),frozenset({1,2}),frozenset({1,3}),frozenset({2,3})}
        Faces={frozenset({0,1,2}),frozenset({0,1,3}),frozenset({0,2,3}),frozenset({1,2,3})}
    elif userInput1==2:
        Vertices=[(0,0,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(-1,0,0),(0,-1,0),(0,0,-1)]
        Edges={frozenset({0,1}),frozenset({0,2}),frozenset({0,3}),frozenset({0,4}),frozenset({1,2}),frozenset({2,3}),
               frozenset({3,4}),frozenset({1,4}),frozenset({1,5}),frozenset({2,5}),frozenset({3,5}),frozenset({4,5})}
        Faces={frozenset({0,1,2}),frozenset({0,2,3}),frozenset({0,3,4}),frozenset({0,1,4}),
               frozenset({1,2,5}),frozenset({2,3,5}),frozenset({3,4,5}),frozenset({1,4,5})}
    else:
        Vertices=[(-1,0,0),(1,0,0),(-0.44721359549996,-0.89442719099992,0),(0.44721359549996,0.89442719099992,0),
                  (-0.44721359549996,-0.27639320225002,-0.85065080835204),(-0.44721359549996,-0.27639320225002,0.85065080835204),
                  (0.44721359549996,0.27639320225002,-0.85065080835204),(0.44721359549996,0.27639320225002,0.85065080835204),
                  (-0.44721359549996,0.72360679774998,-0.52573111211913),(-0.44721359549996,0.72360679774998,0.52573111211913),
                  (0.44721359549996,-0.72360679774998,-0.52573111211913),(0.44721359549996,-0.72360679774998,0.52573111211913)]
        Edges={frozenset({0,2}),frozenset({0,5}),frozenset({2,5}),frozenset({0,9}),frozenset({5,9}),frozenset({8,9}),frozenset({0,8}),
               frozenset({3,8}),frozenset({3,9}),frozenset({1,3}),frozenset({1,6}),frozenset({3,6}),frozenset({6,8}),frozenset({6,10}),
               frozenset({2,10}),frozenset({1,10}),frozenset({6,10}),frozenset({4,6}),frozenset({4,10}),frozenset({0,4}),frozenset({2,4}),
               frozenset({4,8}),frozenset({7,9}),frozenset({1,7}),frozenset({5,7}),frozenset({7,11}),frozenset({3,7}),frozenset({1,11}),
               frozenset({2,11}),frozenset({5,11}),frozenset({10,11})}
        Faces={frozenset({0,2,4}),frozenset({0,4,8}),frozenset({0,8,9}),frozenset({0,5,9}),frozenset({5,7,9}),frozenset({0,2,5}),
               frozenset({2,5,11}),frozenset({5,7,11}),frozenset({1,7,11}),frozenset({1,3,7}),frozenset({3,7,9}),frozenset({1,10,11}),
               frozenset({2,10,11}),frozenset({4,6,8}),frozenset({3,8,9}),frozenset({1,3,6}),frozenset({3,6,8}),frozenset({1,6,10}),
               frozenset({4,6,10}),frozenset({2,4,10})}

    iterations=int(input('\nInput desired depth of refinement:\n\n'))

    refine(Vertices,Edges,Faces,iterations)

    # Finding circumference of polyhedron
    
    greatCircleVertices=set()

    if iterations>0:
        for i in range(len(Vertices)):
            if Vertices[i][0]==0:
                greatCircleVertices.add(i)

    greatCircleEdges={edge for edge in Edges if edge.issubset(greatCircleVertices)}

    circumference=0

    for edge in greatCircleEdges:
        distanceVector=np.array([0,0,0])
        constant=-1
        for vertex in edge:
            constant=constant*(-1)
            distanceVector=np.add(distanceVector,np.multiply(constant,np.array(Vertices[vertex])))
        circumference=circumference+norm(distanceVector,2)

    print('\n Circumference = '+str(circumference))
            
    # Plotting

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.set(xlim=(-1,1), ylim=(-1,1), zlim=(-1,1))
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([ [ Vertices[i] for i in face] for face in Faces],edgecolors='k',facecolors='w',alpha=0.85))
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([ [ Vertices[i] for i in edge] for edge in greatCircleEdges],edgecolors='red',linewidths=1,zorder=200))
    plt.axis('off')
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()

    userInput2='y'

    # Asking if user wants additional refinement
    
    while(userInput2=='y'):
        userInput2=input('\nRefine further? (y or n)\n\n')
        if userInput2=='y':
            additionalIterations=int(input('\nInput desired depth of additional refinement:\n\n'))
            refine(Vertices,Edges,Faces,additionalIterations)
            iterations=iterations+additionalIterations
            print('\n Total depth = '+str(iterations))

            # Finding circumference of polyhedron
    
            greatCircleVertices=set()

            if iterations>0:
                for i in range(len(Vertices)):
                    if Vertices[i][0]==0:
                        greatCircleVertices.add(i)

            greatCircleEdges={edge for edge in Edges if edge.issubset(greatCircleVertices)}

            circumference=0

            for edge in greatCircleEdges:
                distanceVector=np.array([0,0,0])
                constant=-1
                for vertex in edge:
                    constant=constant*(-1)
                    distanceVector=np.add(distanceVector,np.multiply(constant,np.array(Vertices[vertex])))
                circumference=circumference+norm(distanceVector,2)

            print('\n Circumference = '+str(circumference))
    
            # Plotting

            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
            ax.set(xlim=(-1,1), ylim=(-1,1), zlim=(-1,1))
            ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([ [ Vertices[i] for i in f] for f in Faces],edgecolors='k',facecolors='w',alpha=0.85))
            plt.axis('off')
            ax.set_aspect('equal')
            plt.show()

while(True):
    main()
```

Is there a way for the great circle to always be shown? Can I set the edgecolor of specific edges rather than plotting twice? Any help is greatly appreciated! (Note: the relevant code block is under the first # plotting in main().)